# Openpyxl: iterate on range of cell

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would write to a range of cells a sequence of values taken from a list.

**VIEW**

```
def create_excel(avg):
    wb = load_workbook('output/file_base.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active

    ws['D20'] = avg[0]
    ws['D21'] = avg[1]
    ws['D22'] = avg[2]
    ws['D23'] = avg[3]
    ws['D24'] = avg[4]
    ws['D25'] = avg[5]


    wb.save('out.xlsx')

    return 1
```

I would do this using a loop, and I have tried the following:

```
start, stop = 20,26
for index, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows()):
    if start < index < stop:
        ws.cell[index] = avg[index]
```

but it returns:

```
list index out of range
```

How can I can do this? I am using openpyxl 2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify row and columns as follows:

```
import openpyxl

avg = [10, 20, 25, 5, 32, 7]

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('output/file_base.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

for row, entry in enumerate(avg, start=20):
    ws.cell(row=row, column=4, value=entry)

wb.save('out.xlsx')
```

This iterates over your averages, and uses Python's [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function to count for you at the same time. By telling it to start with a value of 20, it can then be used as the row value for writing to a cell.

Comment: Please can you tell what is `value=entry` here?

Comment: `value` is used to specify the contents of the cell, and `entry` is one of the entries from `avg`. On the first iteration, `row` will be `20` and `entry` will be `10`.